# databaseChangeLog does not contain a list of entries. Each changeSet must begin ' - changeSet:'

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, liquibase

I want to create mysql person table with liquibase. But I'm getting one error so

> Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: databaseChangeLog does not contain a list of entries. Each changeSet must begin ' - changeSet:'

**db.changelog-master.yaml**

```
databaseChangeLog:
  -includeAll:
    path: db/changelog/v-0.1/
```

**20201015-01-create-person-table.yaml**

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 20201015-01
      author: nursultankhalilov
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: persons
            columns:
              - column:
                name: person_id
                type: bigint
                autoIncrement: true
                constraints:
                  primaryKey: true
                  primaryKeyName: person_pk
                  nullable: false
              - column:
                name: person_name
                type: VARCHAR(255)
                constraints:
                  nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: person_surname
                  type: VARCHAR(255)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: person_email
                  type: VARCHAR(255)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
                    unique: true
              - column:
                  name: person_phone
                  type: VARCHAR(20)
```

Packet structure:

[image: this pic show packet structure]

What am I doing wrong? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there should be a space in "-includeAll" after a dash